# Flutter how open drawer from deep nested widget?

Tags: flutter, navigation-drawer

`Drawer` is custom widget `MenuDrawer()`. It is located on the same level as `BottomNavigationBar`. This is done so that when opening new screens, they do not display the `BottomNavigationBar` and the entire surface of the screen was clean. This works, but only if I try to call the drawer from the next widget inside `BottomNavigationBar`. This can be done using `Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer()`

But if I try to call drawer from widgets which are nested deep inside then it doesn't work.
I tried to use all the tips that I found, wrap in a `builder` or use `Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer()`. It seems that the `context is lost` and the drawer does not open. If you have any ideas or I missed something, I will be grateful.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _systemBackButtonPressed,
      child: Scaffold(
        drawer: const MenuDrawer(),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(...),
          ],
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          onTap: _onItemTapped,
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          top: false,
          child: IndexedStack(
            index: _selectedIndex,
            children: const <Widget>[
              MenuNavigator(),
              CabinetNavigator(),
              SearchNavigator(),
              ContactsNavigator(),
              CartNavigator()
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create a global key variable and pass it here.

For Example

```dart
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> globalScaffoldKey = GlobalKey();

class YourMainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const YourMainScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<YourMainScreen> createState() => _YourMainScreenState();
}

class _YourMainScreenState extends State<YourMainScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _systemBackButtonPressed,
      child: Scaffold(
        key: globalScaffoldKey, // Global Key
        drawer: const MenuDrawer(),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(...),
          ],
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          onTap: _onItemTapped,
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          top: false,
          child: IndexedStack(
            index: _selectedIndex,
            children: const <Widget>[
              MenuNavigator(),
              CabinetNavigator(),
              SearchNavigator(),
              ContactsNavigator(),
              CartNavigator()
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then, you can open the drawer from anywhere by calling

```dart
globalScaffoldKey.currentState!.openDrawer()
```

Comment: Thanks you helped me a lot, your solution works, but yours is a bit incomplete. To get access to the "globalScaffoldKey" it will need to be passed along the chain to all child widgets. This is a common thing in flutter, but maybe someone does not know.

Comment: Just declare the key outside of the widget to make it global so that we dont have to pass it via constructor.